# How can I triangulate a point given geographic coordinates and their angle in Python?

Tags: python, math, geometry, coordinates

I've been trying to figure this problem out for quite a while. There are x number of points but we can just call it three for now that each have geographic coordinates and an angle towards the unknown point. The points should form a line with their angle and intersect at or around the unknown point. I will attach my solution which seems to be working but finding real data to use is troublesome in testing. To explain my code here's what it does in steps:
Converts the coordinates to Cartesian coordinates, tries to find the intersection between the lines created from the points and their angle, then takes all the intersections and finds the average of where the unknown point may be. The max distance variable limits the distance an intersection can be from the original points(Helps cut down on points that are nearly parallel and lines take a long time and computation to intersect). The error margin is used to make sure every intersection is within the defined margin and if not decides there is not enough accuracy to determine the unknown point.

```
import numpy as np
from pyproj import Proj, Transformer
from haversine import haversine, Unit
import utm


def convert_gps_to_cartesian(lat, lon, zone):
    proj_latlon = Proj(proj='latlong', datum='WGS84')
    proj_xy = Proj(proj="utm", zone=zone, datum='WGS84')
    transformer = Transformer.from_proj(proj_latlon, proj_xy)
    return transformer.transform(lon, lat)


def convert_cartesian_to_gps(x, y, zone):
    proj_latlon = Proj(proj='latlong', datum='WGS84')
    proj_xy = Proj(proj="utm", zone=zone, datum='WGS84')
    transformer = Transformer.from_proj(proj_xy, proj_latlon)
    return transformer.transform(x, y)


def get_intersection_point(line1, line2, max_distance=np.inf):
    point1, direction1 = line1
    point2, direction2 = line2

    a = np.array([direction1, -direction2]).T
    b = np.array(point1) - np.array(point2)

    try:
        x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
        if np.isscalar(x):
            return None
    except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
        return None

    intersection = point1 + x[0] * direction1

    if np.linalg.norm(intersection - point1) > max_distance or np.linalg.norm(intersection - point2) > max_distance:
        return None

    return intersection


def get_estimated_location(points, directions, error_margin, zone):
    lines = []
    for point, direction in zip(points, directions):
        x, y = convert_gps_to_cartesian(*point, zone)
        direction_cart = np.array([np.cos(np.radians(direction)), np.sin(np.radians(direction))])
        lines.append((np.array([x, y]), direction_cart))

    intersections = []
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(lines)):
            intersection = get_intersection_point(lines[i], lines[j], 90000)
            if intersection is not None:
                intersections.append(intersection)

    intersections = [i for i in intersections if i is not None]  # Exclude None values

    # Check error margin
    for i in range(len(intersections)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(intersections)):
            if haversine(convert_cartesian_to_gps(*intersections[i], zone),
                         convert_cartesian_to_gps(*intersections[j], zone),
                         unit=Unit.KILOMETERS) > error_margin:
                return None

    if len(intersections) < 2:  # If intersections is empty
        return None

    estimated_location = np.mean(intersections, axis=0)
    estimated_location_gps = convert_cartesian_to_gps(*estimated_location, zone)
    return estimated_location_gps


points = [(52.5200, 13.4050), (52.5097, 13.3763), (52.5270, 13.4124)]  # Berlin, Brandenburg Gate, and Alexanderplatz
directions = [180, 45, -90]
error_margin = 10

zone = utm.from_latlon(points[0][0], points[0][1])[2]

print(get_estimated_location(points, directions, error_margin, zone)[::-1])
```